# How input accepts only HEX numbers

Tags: javascript, html, validation, hex

I have an input field and I want to give this field a validation that accepts only hex numbers. So it should accept numbers from 0 to 9 and letters from A to F.

Here is my input field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="9" maxlength="2">
```

How do you think I can achieve this?

Comment: Use the RegExpresion `[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+` to check the input value

Comment: Try using input type="color" instead, a color picker.. for more details check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color)

Comment: How can I do that? @MuXeD

Comment: pattern="[0-9a-fA-F]+" should add this into my input field? @MuXeD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="validate($event)" tabindex="9" maxlength="2">
```

And in your `.js`

```js
validate(event) {
   let regEx = "^[-+]?[0-9A-Fa-f]+\.?[0-9A-Fa-f]*?$";
   let isHex = regEx.match(event.target.value);
   // Do things with isHex Boolean
}
```

**EDIT**:
If you need to prevent you can do something like this

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  let regEx = /^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/;
  let isHex = regEx.test(event.target.value.toString());
  if(!isHex) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" tabindex="9" maxlength="2">
```

Comment: If you only need for colors the regExp is `\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}\b`

Comment: Thats a great answers, Thanks. But is there any soludtion how can I avoid to enter the wrong value? For example, not to enter 'w' in this case?

Comment: I don't need this for colors. I want to validate the input field, not allow user enter something else than RegExp and also user should be able to enter only two digits which is solved with maxlength="2"

Comment: Yes, you can test the value and if is invalid prevent input. I edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex expression for your problem i write a simple example for your input

```
<input type="text" id="hex_code" name="hex_code" pattern="#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}([0-9a-fA-F]{3})?" title="in valid hex code"><br><br>
```

another option is input type color like @groov_guy comment but you need to convert rgb values to hex like this post , so you need to set default value with hex format then  when client change color you can get new hex code. a basic codes as below

```
<input type="color" onchange="printColor(event)" value="#ff0000">

function printColor(ev) {
  const color = ev.target.value;
  console.log(color) // you can get hex value
  
}
```

[sample link](https://jsfiddle.net/La8ogspb/)

https://css-tricks.com/color-inputs-a-deep-dive-into-cross-browser-differences/

Comment: Your pattern is wrong, you are missing `#` and hex is either 3 or 6 long definitely not 32. This might count as complete hex pattern `#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}([0-9a-fA-F]{3})?`

Comment: @Akxe İ edited with your regex pattern thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add the pattern attribute to the input. This **won't prevent** the user to write invalid information, but when submitting it will show a message. Also, you can add some styles to show that something is wrong **before** submit.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="9" maxlength="2" pattern="[0-9a-fA-F]+">

<style>
input:invalid {
  border: red solid 3px;
}
</style>
```